# How to enable "Google Maps Android API v2" in developers console

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have developed an application to display my location on google map. When I run the program, its showing the below error.

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to enable "Google Maps Android API v2". I have found a question on the same. I am not quiet clear on how to follow that step.

[image]

Could you please help me solve this?

Comment: which keystore you have used to generate SHA-1? debug or release?

Comment: Hi! I have used release key store.

Comment: This error showing in release APK. Am i right?

Comment: man have u discovered the error... Now i am stuck at this point.. Help me if you could

Answer (score 9):

In the developer console go to API Manager

Fist you will need some some API Keys.

- Go to Credentials.
- Select **Create credentials** and choose "API key" and "Android key".
- In the next screen put any name for your credential.
- In the **+Add package name fingerprint** write your package name (com.sourcey.materialwhatever) and the fingerprint that appears in your log (E4:...:B9).

[image: API Manager - Credentials]

Now from the API Manager go to Overview

- Look for "Google Maps Android API" and enable it.

[image: API Manager - Overview]

You probably got a debug keystore when you installed android sdk, with it you could check your fingerprint using the command: 
($HOME/.android/debug.keystore is the default location)

```
keytool -list -v -keystore .android/debug.keystore
```

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Hi Edwin... I have followed all these steps while creating my project. I cross checked now and the API is enabled! Still I am getting the error.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error or a new one? the apk was generated by the same computer you submited the fingerprint?

Comment: Yes, I am still getting the same error and the its the same computer.

Comment: in the manifest is the API Key correct? i think it would have show a different error but maybe no
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="<YOUR_API_KEY>"/>

Answer (score 7):

Nothing else worked for me, but this solved my problem:

1. Open your console (console.developers.google.com)
2. Select Credentials from left
3. Click on your API key
4. Click on API Restrictions under Key Restrictions
5. Click on Select API and
6. "Maps SDK for Android" to your API Restrictions list
7. "Save"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It takes > 5 minutes after enabling the google map API.