# Google Maps Activity doesn't work

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, maps

I created a new Android-Studio project, I got the API KEY and my Multidex is enabled but I'm getting this error in my logcat:

```
01-26 16:55:51.989 5606-5750/com.example.maptestdel E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
01-26 16:55:52.121 5606-5751/com.example.maptestdel E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
01-26 16:55:52.121 5606-5751/com.example.maptestdel E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-26 16:55:52.125 5606-5751/com.example.maptestdel E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                               Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                               Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                API Key: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZBLABLABLA
                                                                                Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 8B:9C:A2:53:68:BE:3D:3F:4A:53:39:F7:71:83:E6:EB:F4:63:06:6C;com.example.maptestdel
01-26 16:55:53.767 5606-5748/com.example.maptestdel W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
```

How can I enable my Google Maps Android API v2?
The API key is new, if I start the app on my Huawei P8 Lite I'm getting a white screen with the Google logo at the bottom-left.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.maptestdel"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: what does your google console say?

Comment: Please do not post real API keys when posting questions. That should be private.

Answer (score 0):

[How to enable "Google Maps Android API v2" in developers console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371754/how-to-enable-google-maps-android-api-v2-in-developers-console)

Please follow the above link . You can create your developers account on google console , create a brand new project , create keys for Android and enable required map api's .

Answer (score 0):

There might be many thing that you are missing as you did't paste your whole code

> In manifest :

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

> In Gradle

Top level Build File

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Project level build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and finally in your Google Developer Console you have to **enable the Google Maps Android API**

Try this and let me know if this work for you or not