# Google Maps not loading when key restrictions are enabled: Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I know this has been asked several times before but I am not sure whether my fix is proper. I am using Google Maps in my app. The google map is not loading and I am getting error as,

```
E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
```

My manifest is having,

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

My gradle file is below,

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
}
```

EDIT:

My fragment,

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

This is my layout where I am using the fragment,

```
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/map_area"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <fragment 
         android:id="@+id/map" 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

     <Button
          android:id="@+id/map_button"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/map"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:text="View Map and Directions"
          android:textColor="#ffffff"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

I have gone through some of the below links but none of these seems to work,

- [How to enable "Google Maps Android API v2" in developers console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371754/how-to-enable-google-maps-android-api-v2-in-developers-console)
- [Google Maps Android API v2 Authorization failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure)
- [Google Maps v2 Authorization failure. Different SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656480/google-maps-v2-authorization-failure-different-sha1)
- [Google Maps Android API v2 Authorization failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure)

After going through several links, I managed to make my Google Maps work on removing the key restrictions from the google console. Is this the correct solution? Can anyone help me in fixing the issue with the Google Maps?

NOTE: I already have my Google Maps API Enable in Console.

Comment: Post your `gradle` file,have you add this dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'

Comment: try to add `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in manifest file

Comment: @Gowthaman The gradle file is already there.

Comment: @ArpitPrajapati I already have this in my gradle file.. now edited the question with it.

Comment: post your .xml file which have fragment tag and remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'` because when you have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` then you don't need to add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'`

Comment: your fragment file looks fine, can post .java file code which contains onMapReady() method

Comment: you need to add your package name and SHA key..

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the google map api from google console

Below are the step to enable the google map api .

- [Go to Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
- Click on the dropdown and select 'create a project'.
  Enter Project Name.
- now click on Navigation drawer and select API Manager.
  Enable google places api.

Comment: I already have my Google Maps API Enable in Console. My Google Map is also loading when I set the key restriction to NONE from the console.